# Simple Text Editor in Linux with Conditional Formatting

Tags: text-editor, formatter

I am looking for a simple Text Editor on Linux (Arch, preferrably) with **conditional formatting**. I have noted [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/74961/is-there-any-simple-graphical-text-editor-with-syntax-highlighting).

I am not looking for a syntax highlighter. I need conditional formatting, where i can :

- Create a list of words, which will be autoformatted if encountered in text. e.g. : I should be able to specify : Word : EXAMPLEWORD and Format : Red, Bold. (The exact method of the specification does not matter. Perhaps an XML file, perhaps through a GUI ...) Then , if I write :
  AKAKAKedhsdlsjfdssj ExAmPleWoRd (NOTE : that case should not matter) -
  Then, the word ExAmPleWoRd should automatically be made Red, and bold.
- I would be able to highlight matching parentheses and brackets and braces, as I choose. That is, if I specify {} and [] then, it would highlight matching {} and [], but not <>. If at a later point, I add <> , then it should highlight that too.

Is there something like that out there?
Thank you.

Comment: You didn't rule out anything, and since you are on Linux, the choices are either vi based or emacs based (With the new contender being vscode).
Don't know if I have an answer, but check this vim solution: https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Highlight_multiple_words

Comment: Also check out [spacemacs](https://www.spacemacs.org/) it has sooo many layers available, I'm pretty sure it might be able to do what you want.
But - not really a 'simple Text Editor'

Comment: Notepad++ let's you define syntax for new languages. https://www.technipages.com/how-to-configure-the-syntax-highlighting-in-notepad

Answer (score 1):

The [CudaText](https://cudatext.github.io/) (free editor) can help with this, but not solve this out of the box.

- For item 1, you must write a plugin in python, it must handle `on_change` event and highlight all needed words in text using `ed.attr()` API. Plugin may get its words how you will like it.
- For item 2, CudaText supports this already. It has the option `bracket_highlight` for pair brackets highlighting, for any of them.